# Is there any way to Ignore(Bypass) BeansException(BeanCreationException) and go on in Spring?

Tags: spring, exception, javabeans

In the load-time, Spring Container initializes Beans... when It finds the Bean-related error, It stops and roll-backs(not exact terminology)... as I know.

Here's our condition.
 We are developing a kind of Web Application System. (It's Huge)
 There's several thousand Spring beans.
 Our Client requested the following.
 "During WAS Restarting, Even though One or Some Beans have problem(load-time error), Ignore those, System must go on..."

Already we met that request by modifying Spring's source codes... but It's not good(proper) way, I think.

Well...
 Is there another way to Ignore BeansException?
 (Firstly, I persuaded the Client to understand that Ignoring is not good way, but failed.)

Answer (score 1):

I think one option would be to use annotations and the @Autowire tag, setting required to false.  This way, if Spring finds the bean, it autowires it in.  If it doesn't, you get a null reference.

If that's not an option, then you could implement ApplicationContextAware and wire things together manually using the application context you get.  I like the first option better.

In no circumstance would I ever consider modifying the Spring code, however.  I think this is dangerous, and locks you into having to either support your custom Spring libs forever, or never updating Spring ever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. ^^
Your first option, sad to say... it's not an option for me. =_+' (I have not the power about code standard.)
and second... it's very bothering I know...
Hmm... As expected and searched, there's no smart and clean way... -_-;;;

Comment: No mater how you end up solving this, if it were me I would, at all cost, push to not make changes directly to the Spring source code.  I think you are only asking for massive amounts of trouble.  Anyhow, good luck.

Comment: Would making some of your beans lazy loaded rather than eager solve the problem partially?